# Building and installing mediapipe windows. getting error Permission denied: for opencv_world3410.dll

Tags: python-3.x, windows, opencv, bazel, mediapipe

I am using windows 10 OS for building Mediapipe library locally.
Environment setup:

- python3.10
- windows 10 os
- bazel version = 3.7.2
- visual studio 2019

Followed the instructions from [this link](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/getting_started/install.html#installing-on-windows) for building using bazel.
with some hick-ups I am able to build the specified hello world from the same above link.

With help of friend I could find building command for hands module.

**command1 for building hand_tracking**

```
bazel build -c opt --define MEDIAPIPE_DISABLE_GPU=1 --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH="C://python_310//python.exe" mediapipe/examples/desktop/hand_tracking:hand_tracking_cpu
```

command 2 for running same.

```
set GLOG_logtostderr=1

.\bazel-bin\mediapipe\examples\desktop\hand_tracking\hand_tracking_cpu --calculator_graph_config_file=.\mediapipe\graphs\hand_tracking\hand_tracking_desktop_live.pbtxt
```

This is running just like this link: [press run button on top right](https://viz.mediapipe.dev/demo/hand_tracking)

I need this as a library installed in my venv.
I dont want the readily available pip install mediapipe. as it is not detecting some hand moments correctly. If I build my own on my pc, it is detecting.

I tried this command below,

```
(mediapipe_venv) C:\dev\mediapipe_repo\mediapipe>python setup.py install
```

After building and when I run this setup.py install, it is failing as below.

```
Warning: skipping import of repository 'pybind11' because it already exists.
WARNING: C:/dev/mediapipe_repo/mediapipe/mediapipe/framework/BUILD:54:24: in cc_library rule //mediapipe/framework:calculator_cc_proto: target '//mediapipe/framework:calculator_cc_proto' depends on deprecated target '@com_google_protobuf//:cc_wkt_protos': Only for backward compatibility. Do not use.
WARNING: C:/dev/mediapipe_repo/mediapipe/mediapipe/framework/tool/BUILD:182:24: in cc_library rule //mediapipe/framework/tool:field_data_cc_proto: target '//mediapipe/framework/tool:field_data_cc_proto' depends on deprecated target '@com_google_protobuf//:cc_wkt_protos': Only for backward compatibility. Do not use.
INFO: Analyzed target //mediapipe/python:_framework_bindings.so (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //mediapipe/python:_framework_bindings.so up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/mediapipe/python/_framework_bindings.so
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.815s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'build\\lib.win-amd64-3.10\\mediapipe\\python\\opencv_world3410.dll'

(mediapipe_venv) C:\dev\mediapipe_repo\mediapipe>
```

Highlighting error from above.

**error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mediapipe\python\opencv_world3410.dll'**

Please suggest me if I am following anything wrong.

I am new to building libs locally. and new for BAZEL.

Answer (score 1):

The command line you're using does not have access to 'build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\mediapipe\python\opencv_world3410.dll'

Run the same command in a command line with administrative privileges.